# Pass data to another form and get response

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to pass data (a 16 digit key) to another site which will validate the key and return a response.  I want to grab the response and check if it's a valid key on my side so I can do some extra stuff with it.

Is this possible?  If not, why can't it be done?

**EDIT:**
Ok here's the process. I am grabbing this key from a user input, which can be accessed by grabbing the POST data. After, the data needs to be sent into another form with 1 input field on another site. Ideally, this will produce a result that I can grab on my end.

Comment: I can think of three possible entities involved in this: host 1, client 1 and host 2.  Can you please describe how you want the data to flow among those (or others)?  Hosts can communicate with anyone.  Javascript clients are subject to restrictions for security reasons.  We can't answer your question without more detail about who requests the data from what and then where it gets passed to.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok here's the process.  I am grabbing this key from a user input, which can be accessed by grabbing the POST data.  After, the data needs to be sent into another form with 1 input field on another site.  Ideally, this will produce a result that I can grab on my end.

Comment: Please add this info to the question itself (there's an Edit button) so everyone sees it and so the question is clear.  Is it the browser sending it to another site or your PHP script on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sample test code to give you an idea of calling a remote site behind the scenes:

```
$key = $_POST['key']

// Create a curl handle to the remote checking server
$ch = curl_init('http://remoteurl/?key=' . $key); 

// Execute 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
// Get the reply back
$reply = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch); 

// Do stuff with the reply
if ($reply == '...')
  // Save $key?!
```

Comment: I just checked the site and it does not set the key in the url... instead, it's done all with AJAX.

Comment: the above would still work, but you'll have to look at php.net/curl documentation of how to pass POST variables ... it's another two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, it's possible and there are many ways to accomplish it.

cURL is probably going to be your best bet.

Or you could use sockets and directly connect to the target machine on port 80 and throw an HTTP request with form data on it for ultimate control.

Or you could also do it on the client side with javascript.